# Query check where

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I'm trying to check in a NodeJS query where a user his id is e.g. 1 and his private_number is 25, the following code doesn't work.

```
query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '+pool.escape(user)+', `private_number` ='+pool.escape(number), function(err, row) { //get if the player has a query with the same code

});
```

Is this even properly possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can use template strings

```
query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = ${pool.escape(user)} AND  
private_number = ${pool.escape(number)}`), function(err, row) {
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

P.S. when you have multiple conditions in `WHERE` clause you need to 'connect' them with logical operator like `AND` or `OR`

Comment: Then this would work..
`SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '+pool.escape(user)+' AND `private_number` ='+pool.escape(number)` or wouldn't it?